# $D_6$, regular hexagon.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, dihedral-groups

Find a subgroup of  $D_6$ where $D_6$ is the regular hexagon, with 12 symmetries.
$$
D_6 = \{ e, r, r^2, r^3, r^4, r^5, a, ar, ar^2, ar^3, ar^4, ar^5\}
$$
where $r^6 = e$. And the $r^n$ represent rotations, and $ar^n$ represent reflections.

When I do the Cayley table for D6, what is the product of $(ar)(ar)$ ? 
I would say it is $a^2(r^2)$, but that is not part of the symmetries.

In other words, what is $a$ squared? I know that $D_6$ is abelian, so $r^2$ times something. And does the value of $a$ depend on the value of $n$?

Thank you.

Comment: First of all, $a$ is the reflection.  $ar^n$ is $n$ rotations followed by a reflection.  What is $j$ supposed to be?  Lastly, $D_6$ is **not** abelian.

Comment: Sorry, I mispelled it, I meant a.

Comment: You're right that you need to know what $ra$ is in terms of the elements you listed.  Why don't you make yourself a hexagon and figure out geometrically which value of $n$ makes $ar^n = ra$?